# iOS RESTful POST call works in UIWebView but not when calling from thread

Tags: objective-c, ios, rest, post, webserver

I am trying to create an authentication system in an iOS app that allows a user to log in as well as register if they do not already have an account. I got the login system completely up and running yesterday, but when I got the code set up for the registration system, the code would not even ping the server. I then tried to test the login system again, and the code will not ping the server now either.

Relevant code for the RegistrationTableViewController (it's a custom TVC that contains text fields in some of the cells - think of the view to create a new calendar event, for example):

```
- (IBAction)signUpButtonPressed { 
    // Get the values out of the text fields that the user has filled out.
    NSString *email = self.emailTextField.text;
    NSString *firstName = self.firstNameTextField.text;
    NSString *lastName = self.lastNameTextField.text;
    NSString *password = self.passwordTextField.text;
    // Assuming that sign-up could potentially take a noticeable amount of time, run the
    // process on a separate thread to avoid locking the UI.
    dispatch_queue_t signUpQueue = dispatch_queue_create("sign-up authenticator", NULL);
    dispatch_async(signUpQueue, ^{
        // self.brain refers to a SignUpBrain property. See the code for the class below.
        [self.brain signUpUsingEmail:email firstName:firstName lastName:lastName  
          andPassword:password];  
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowMainFromSignUp" sender:self];  
        });  
    });  
    dispatch_release(signUpQueue);  
}
```

Relevant code for the SignUpBrain:

```
- (void)signUpUsingEmail:(NSString *)email firstName:(NSString *)firstName
                lastName:(NSString *)lastName andPassword:(NSString *)password {
    self.email = email;
    self.firstName = firstName;
    self.lastName = lastName;
    self.password = password;

    // Handle sign-up web calls.
    NSMutableURLRequest *signUpRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL 
      URLWithString:@"URL GOES HERE"]]; // obviously there's an actual URL in real code
    NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"uname=%@&pw=%@&fname=%@&lname=%@", 
      email, password, firstName, lastName];
//NSLog(postString);
    [signUpRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [signUpRequest setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *signUpConnection = 
      [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:signUpRequest delegate:self];
    [signUpConnection start];

    // Store any user data.
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    self.signUpResponse = data;
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *jsonLoginResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
      options:0 error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(error.description);
    }
    NSLog(jsonLoginResults.description);

    // Return whether the user has successfully been registered.
    // If success is 1, then registration has been completed successfully. 0 if not.
    if ([jsonLoginResults objectForKey:@"status"]) {
        NSLog(@"Success!");
    }
}
```

I will also note that I created a test that uses these same web calls in a UIWebView, and it works successfully.

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything or include any more of the code! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using a secondary thread for the NSURLConnection? While processing the result is appropriate for the secondary thread, when you're using it asynchronously I don't think there's much reason to avoid using NSURLConnection on the main thread.

Comment: @StevenFisher I was under the impression that starting the connection and receiving the result was expensive enough that it would need to occur on a separate thread so that the UI is not blocked while it is being fetched. Is this not correct? I'm very new to the concept of multithreading, so I could be off-base.

Comment: I haven't observed that, and Apple's suggestion has been using async calls on the main thread. Networking is mostly done on a dedicated (not main) thread. The cost to the main thread is going to be whatever is in your delegate methods. Flush your `NSMutableData` in `didReceiveResponse` (cheap), append to the `MSMutableData` in `didReceiveData` (reasonably cheap), and dispatch to an off-thread queue in `connectionDidFinishLoading` for the processing. The dispatch itself is reasonably cheap, and the processing will be off-thread.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be expecting to receive the entire response in `didReceiveData:`. That's just a chunk of data. The response isn't complete until `connectionDidFinishLoading` is called.

Comment: I'm going to put this in an answer, writing in comments is too awkward. I resisted at first because I didn't think I was really answering your question, but now I think this the answer you really need. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, you don't need to run networking operations on a different thread.

What you need to avoid is synchronous operation on the main thread. This will cause iOS to kill your application, since it will stop responding to events while the network transfer is busy.

Apple's suggestion to is to use asynchronous operation on the main thread, rather than synchronous operation on another thread.

Using asynchronous operation will cause the networking itself to run in the background. You can consider this a dedicated thread by Apple. Your delegate methods will be called in the correct sequence on the main thread to catch up with networking as iOS determines it is appropriate.

### Using NSURLConnection

Apple includes an example of how to use `NSURLConnection` in URL Loading System Programming Guide, [Using NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE). It's a short article, full of simple code examples. You should spend a few minutes to read this.

In a nutshell, here's the pattern:

- Keep a `NSMutableData` for your response data.
- Clear the contents `NSMutableData` instance in `didReceiveResponse`. (You may receive multiple `didReceiveResponse` events as you're redirected, but you should only use data from the last one.)
- Append the data you receive from `didReceiveData` to the `NSMutableData`. Don't try to process it immediately; you will *usually* receive multiple `didReceiveData` events for a single transfer.
- In `connectionDidFinishLoading`, your data is complete. Here, you can do something with it.

When you have all the data, you can either send it to a different thread or (much simpler) `dispatch_async` to a queue that isn't running on the main thread. See Listing 5, "Example connectionDidFinishLoading: implementation" of [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-170129).

The idea here is that your start (or restart) accumulating data in `didReceiveResponse:`, append data in your `didReceiveData:`, and actually do something with the data in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`.

It **is** possible to run an `NSURLConnection` on another thread, of course. That thread will need to be using a run loop to receive the delegate events from networking. But unless there's some reason you **need** a separate thread, using asynchronous networking is Apple's solution to this.

Using `NSURLConnection` requires a class member to accumulate data as its transferred. That means that if you're going to have multiple simultaneous transfers, you'll need something more complicated. Probably a wrapper class to drive `NSURLConnection`, and keep each response separate. By the time you've written this wrapper class, you've probably written a naive version of `AFHTTPRequestOperation`, a part of AFNetworking.

Assuming you only have a single transfer going on at once, the code looks a bit like this:

```
- (void)signUpUsingEmail:(NSString *)email firstName:(NSString *)firstName
                lastName:(NSString *)lastName andPassword:(NSString *)password {

    // set up your connection here, but don't start it yet.

    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init]; // receivedData should be a class member
    [signUpConnection start];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // do something with error here
    // if you're not using ARC, release connection & receivedData here
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    dispatch_async(someQueue, ^{
        // do something that takes a long time with receivedData here
        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // go back to your main screen here
        });
    });
    // if you're not using ARC, release connection & receivedData here
}
```

### Using AFNetworking

Now that I've explained all this, I'm going to suggest an alternative. You might be better off using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/).

AFNetworking is an open source third party library. Its most basic classes wrap `NSURLConnection` in a `NSOperation` (thus, something that can be added to an `NSOperationQueue`). AFNetworking handles these events I've talked about automatically. Instead, you write a completion block. When you get this block, the transfer has either succeeded or failed. If it's failed, the error is available on the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` instance. If it's succeeded, you can use the data on the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` instance.

(Note: I believe `AFHTTPRequestOperation` actually does run the connection from another thread. However, it's well-written and well-tested code. There's nothing "wrong" with doing this, it's just harder to pull off and usually unnecessary. But if your library does it for you, why not?)

AFNetworking provides some HTTP logic that `NSURLConnection` doesn't. With AFNetworking, you'd just use a `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and set a completion block. All of the above becomes something like:

```
HTTPOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: URLRequest];
HTTPOperation.completionBlock = ^{
    dispatch_async(someQueue, ^{
        // get possible error or content from HTTPOperation
    }
};
[HTTPOperation start];
```

In the past, I've written using NSURLConnection directly. But recently, I've been using AFNetworking more frequently. Unlike some other libraries, it's not a radically different shape than NSURLConnection. In fact, it uses NSURLConnection, just wrapped in a NSOperation (which hopefully Apple will get to any release now). It's worth considering, at least.

Comment: Great response, Steven. Thanks so much. A couple more quick questions before I mark your answer as accepted:

I'm presuming you meant to say "If you keep using `NSURLConnection`"?

What would be your preferred method of flushing the `NSMutableData`? Just calling `resetBytesInRange:` with an `NSRange` covering the `length` of the `NSMutableData`?

Comment: Finally, on your last step, you're saying to move the `NSJSONSerialization` stuff into `connectionDidFinishLoading` in a `dispatch_async` right? But that method as well as `didReceiveResponse` do not exist in the [`NSURLConnectionDelegate` Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I've updated the answer. I actually meant erase the content in didReceiverResponse. The idea is you reset your data in didReceiveResponse, add to it in didReceiveData, and process the data in connectionDidFinishLoading. The connectionDidFinishLoading event is part of `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` instead of `NSURLConnectionDelegate`. I couldn't find a class reference for this, so I've added a link to the example in the URL Loading System Programming Guide.

Comment: So just to clarify, by erasing the content in `didReceiveResponse`, you mean setting the `length` of the `NSMutableData` to 0 like they do in Listing 2 of the URL Loading System Programming Guide?

Comment: And does this also mean I need to make my `SignUpBrain` implement only the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` protocol and not the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol?

Comment: Yes, erase the content by setting the data's length to 0. And yes, it looks like you should be using NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, which inherits from NSURLConnectionDelegate. (These formal protocols are new-ish; I'm still relying on the informal protocols in my code.)

Comment: Ok, Steven, there's actually one more issue I run into. Back in the RegistrationTVC, won't the view instantly segue before the sign up occurs and gets results? I don't want the user to see the main view until after they've definitely signed up.

Comment: I've updated my example connectionDidFinishLoading to show where you'd get back to your main screen.

Comment: This code is in the Model though (`SignUpBrain`). I need to segue to the MainView from the Controller (`RegistrationTableViewController`). The Model has no way of communicating with the View.

Comment: You can either have your modal view comply to a protocol that the brain offers and sends events to, or have your brain send a notification that your modal observes. See NSNotificationCenter.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a blog post about this exact problem a few years back, so it might be a bit out of date: http://www.sortedbits.com/nsurlconnection-in-its-own-thread

It's good to know that NSURLConnection actually does fire properly, but that delegate calls are not received. When you put the NSRunLoop there, it makes sure your connection does not run out of scope in that thread.

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection requires a runloop that is not available on secondary thread by default. If you need to create a connection on secondary thread, add a runloop that runs in NSDefaultRunLoopMode.

Use following code before creating NSURLConnection object. "finished" is an BOOL type iVar that should be updated to YES when connection loading completes.

```
    do {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    } while (!finished);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I took out the multithreading, and the code works. A second question I have, though, is that you should include the code that you mentioned to avoid locking the UI for the user, right? Because nothing about `NSURLConnection` is multithreaded by default? Could you elaborate a bit more on how your code snippet functions?

Answer (score 0):

Every thread has an associated runloop. NSURLConnection for its delegate methods to get fired requires runloop.

In your `- (void)signUpUsingEmail:...` method after `[signUpConnection start];` schedule URL connection to run on that thread(created and managed by GCD) runloop like this -

```
[signUpConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```